# Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I have downloaded mysql ZIP from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=467269

Then extracted it, renamed `my-default.ini` to `my.ini`, set

```
basedir = D:\Apps\MySQL\mysql-5.7.17-winx64
datadir = D:\Apps\MySQL\data5717
```

then started

```
mysqld --console
```

under admin privileges. All was described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html

Unfortunately it prints the following in console:

> [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to
>   create it.

and doesn't work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You probably misunderstood/skipped point 4 in your list, *Initialize MySQL*. It means to either copy an existing data directory there or to create a new one, see [Initializing the Data Directory Manually Using mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) .

To initialize a fresh data directory, you basically (after setting your config file) just have to run either

```sh
bin\mysqld --initialize
```

or

```sh
bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure
```

The latter will set an empty root password.

Comment: mysqld --initialize-insecure
fixed my problem with Wamp64

Comment: If you are using windows, specially Laragon, start by removing the data/mysql-8 directory. Then go and execute mysqld --initialize-insecure from the bin directory of mysql-8.0.27-winx64 or the version of MySQL you are using. Please ensure you have back up your Db

Answer (score 1):

If you set datadir to some other location than basedir, like we do, then you have to COPY, not move, the basedir databases there too.
Apparently mysqld looks for some of it's own stuff in the wrong place. 
After the copy you have to change the owner and group of everything you copied to mysql.

sudo cp -R /usr/local/mysql/data/* /your/own/data/place
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /your/own/data/place

BTW you can't just change the basedir to match the new datadir after the copy.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have to delete the aria_log files:

```
mysql/data/aria_log.00000001
mysql/data/aria_log_control
```

when just start the mysqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Open a console window to the directory that the mysqld.exe file is in and run the following command:

```
mysqld --initialize-insecure --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

Then restart the wamp services.