# Unable to start mysql server on mac for mysql@5.6

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-5.6

I am trying to set up mysql@5.6 on my mac. I had multiple versions of mysql in my local, I removed all of them, installed mysql@5.6 by following these steps as per this post: [After MySQL install via Brew, I get the error - The server quit without updating PID file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating):

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql

brew install mysql@5.6

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.47/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

I did not have any `my.cnf` file inside `/etc`, so I created this with following content:

```
 [mysqld]
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Now while doing **mysql.server start**, getting following error:

```
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/my.pid).
```

I checked the log file, I am seeing following error:

```
   2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.47 started; log sequence number 1603477
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [ERROR] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
2020-04-28 11:17:49 48498 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Then I followed this post: [Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531225/cant-open-the-mysql-plugin-table-please-run-mysql-upgrade-to-create-it), and run following command:

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.47/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure
```

But still I am seeing the same error.

**EDIT:**

I have found my.cnf file, it was located inside /usr/local/etc/

I removed mysqlx-bind-address, now I am getting following errors:

```
2020-04-28 14:16:13 97501 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2020-04-28 14:16:35 98713 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this running following command:

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.47 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

I got this idea from here: https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

Then with `mysql.server start`, mysql DB server is getting up without any error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this problem on my system. Turns out, the problematic line (`mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1`) was in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`, while everyone just says to check `/etc/my.cnf`.

After removing the offending file (probably a leftover from MySQL 8 install), MySQL 5.6 install worked fine.

Comment: You have saved me!! I Had invested almost half of my night and it was started looking like a nightmare. my.cnf was causing issues and hence not starting the system. Thanks a lot!!!